# Hibernate - order the results in a set with xml layout?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables. School and student:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.example.MavenHibernateMysql.School" table="school" catalog="hibernate">
    <id name="schoolId" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="school_id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="schoolName" type="string">
        <column name="school_name" length="20"/>
    </property>
    <set name="students" table="students" cascade="all">
        <key column="school_id"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.example.MavenHibernateMysql.Student" />
    </set>
</class>
```

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.example.MavenHibernateMysql.Student" table="student" catalog="hibernate">
    <id name="studentId" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="student_id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="studentName" type="string">
        <column name="student_name" length="20"/>
    </property>
    <many-to-one name="School" class="com.example.MavenHibernateMysql.School" column="school_id"/>
    <property name="ts" type="java.sql.Timestamp" column="ts"/>
</class>
```

When i select a school and access the students in it they come back in the same order they were inserted. Is it possible to have them ordered by "ts" field?
If so what set should i use in my School java object? At the moment i am using HashSet. Should i use LinkedHashSet?

```
public class School {
private Integer schoolId;
private String schoolName;
private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();

public Integer getSchoolId() {
    return schoolId;
}

public void setSchoolId(Integer schoolId) {
    this.schoolId = schoolId;
}

public String getSchoolName() {
    return schoolName;
}

public void setSchoolName(String schoolName) {
    this.schoolName = schoolName;
}

public Set<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
}

public void setStudents(Set<Student> students) {
    this.students = students;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use an `order by` attribute to let the database do the job or a `sort` attribute to do this by Java, but in the latter case you have to implement a java.lang.Comparator which compares Students by their ts property.

```
<set name="students" table="students" cascade="all" order-by="ts asc">
    <key column="school_id"/>
    <one-to-many class="com.example.MavenHibernateMysql.Student" />
</set>
```

or

```
<set name="students" table="students" cascade="all" sort="your.package.YourComparator">
    <key column="school_id"/>
    <one-to-many class="com.example.MavenHibernateMysql.Student" />
</set>
```

with a Comparator like

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class YourComparator implements Comparator<Student>
{
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2)
    {
        if (o1=null || o1.getTs()==null) return o2==null||o2.getTs()==null?0:-1;
        if (o2=null || o2.getTs()==null) return o1==null||o2.getTs()==null?0:1;
        if (o1.getTs().before(o2.getTs()) return -1;
        if (o1.getTs().after(o2.getTs()) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If you use the `sort` attribute, Hibernate returns a Set that behaves like java.util.TreeSet, if you use `order-by` it behaves like a LinkedHashSet. I don't think that the Set you use in your application logic is important for Hibernate.